# Error: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library

Tags: node.js, deployment, prisma, prisma-binding

I'm facing an issue anyone here to help me with Prisma? I am trying to deploy my Backend API on Cpanel hosting it's created by Prisma MySQL for database design and expressJs.
But, I tried a lot's of ways and I have recharged but never got any solution. when I run

`npx prisma generate or npx prisma migrate`

it's says to me

```
Error: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library. It seems that the current architecture x64 is not supported, or that libc is missing from the system.
Details: Unable to require(`/home/crafiebs/nodevenv/node_api/14/lib/node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.0.x.so.node`)
 /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/crafiebs/nodevenv/node_api/14/lib/node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.0.x.so.node)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install openssl on your server. Maybe this link can help you https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403778152087-How-to-install-OpenSSL

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer the question, or to ask clarification from the OP? If it is indeed an answer, please phrase it as such ("You should install openssl on your server"), see [answer]. If this was not intended to answer the question, please delete this, as the "Your Answer" box is only meant for answer.

Comment: oh thanks guys! sorry iam new here. Just tryng help

Comment: yes! this an answer for de question. Thanks for clarify how to improve my answers!